# Create isochrones of 5 hours plus?

Tags: qgis, isochrone

I am carrying out some work, and my client requires isochrones generated between 1 and 9 hours (daily driving limits in EU). I'm scratching my head at the moment trying to find something that could generate this larger drive time, is this something I can do in QGIS? Esri Drive time analysis maxes out at 5 hours. There are limitations to most services. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: OSM-tools and pgrouting are two tools to create isochrones in QGIS. I don't know about the time limit but it should be simple enough to check the documentation.

Comment: GRASS GIS has the [v.isochrones](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass76/manuals/addons/v.isochrones.html) program. In QGIS you can do something with _v.net.iso_ and _r.cost_ implementaions. I don't see an isochrone limit, but since you need a topological network for that work, seems better to doing it in a PostGIS pgrouting enabled database or in GRASS GIS.